# GRUB Bootloader selection window showing 2 times

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, windows-xp, grub

Currently I have installed 4 os on my 2 HDDs, Windows 7, Windows XP, Ubuntu 14.04 & Open Suse 12.3, in same order.
Before I have Installed Open Suse.
GRUB was showing options:

1. Windows XP
2. Windows 7
3. Ubuntu 14.04

But after I have installed Open Suse 12.3 It shows selection windows 2 times.
For first time it shows:

1. Windows XP
2. Windows 7
3. Linux

After choosing Linux, it again shows following options:

1. Open Suse
2. Windows Bootloader
3. Ubuntu 14.04
4. Ubuntu 14.04 (Safeboot)

Here when I choose Windows Bootloader it again shows first 3 options.:

1. Windows XP
2. Windows 7
3. Linux

But I want selection options to be shown for one time. How to do that?

```
$ grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you installed GRUB both to the MBR of the disk and to the start of a partition with Linux. To install GRUB only to the MBR use

> grub-install /dev/sda

(Provided /dev/sda is your boot drive.)

Comment: Thanks for reply.
But it doesn't work.
Do you have any other suggestion?